# JavaScript code in modal of Bootstrap not run

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal, vue.js

JavaScript code in modal of Bootstrap not run:

in cosole, the error is like this:
[image]
if the code not put in modal,there is no error like above screenshot.

code:(code has not completed,I must let it run first.)

```
<style>
    #image {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div id="gridSystemModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content"  id="app" @submit.prevent="submit">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridModalLabel">upload avatar</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid bd-example-row">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8" style="height: 540px; ">
                            <img id="originalImage" class="card-img-top" src="holder.js/540x540?text=preview&amp;nowrap=true" alt="" style="width: 100%; display: block;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-block">
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">preview：</h6>
                                </div>
                                <img id="preview" alt="avatar" src="holder.js/180x180?text=preview&amp;nowrap=true" style="height: 180px; width: 180px;">
                            </div>

                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="avatar">File input</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="avatar" name="avatar" @change="preview($event)">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">保存</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bd-example bd-example-padded-bottom">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gridSystemModal">
        upload avatar
    </button>
</div>

<script>
    Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').getAttribute('content')

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            avatar: {},
            originalImage:{}
        },
        methods: {
            preview: function(event) {
                var picture = event.target.files;
                $('#preview').attr('src', picture[0]);
                this.avatar=picture[0];
            },
            submit: function(event) {
                var formData=this.businessLicence.formData;
                console.log(formData);

                this.$http.post('/avatar/', formData,{
                    before(request) {
                        if (this.previousRequest) {
                            this.previousRequest.abort();
                        }
                        this.previousRequest = request;
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
                    // success callback
            }, (response) => {
                    // error callback
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('#image').cropper({
        aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
        crop: function (e) {
            // Output the result data for cropping image.
            console.log(e.x);
            console.log(e.y);
            console.log(e.width);
            console.log(e.height);
            console.log(e.rotate);
            console.log(e.scaleX);
            console.log(e.scaleY);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you have at the top of your question you need to include the files that Vue references and you also need to include Jquery

JQUERY

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap:

> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you
>   include plugins individually, make sure to check for these
>   dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery
>   (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Don't forget to init your Modal:

```
<script>
$('#gridSystemModal').modal('show');
</script>
```